Dryer not powering on
Bought a house got a new washer dryer. Dryer doesn't power on. I got it to flicker on once after putting in new fuses. Fuses didnt blow that was checked. Had an electrician out. Says everything is good electrical, its the dryer. Called to get a warranty appliance tech out. He said it was electrical. Called electrician back to have hime walk me through why he thinks its the dryer. He checked from the fuse box to outlet. Everything checked good. Even the dryer plug when disconnected from dryer but plugged into outlet gave right readings but when plugg is connected to dryer, one leg to neutral reads 120 and the other reads 12. It is a 3 prong. Any suggestions would be appreciated

12 means there is a bad connection somewhere.  A loose connection or a broken wire inside of the insulation.  Having it flicker once when fooling around with it, tends to a broken wire.

So its just faulting when put under load essentially?

Did the Dryer power cord come with the unit, or was it your old one.  If it was the old one get a new power cord.  If it came with the dryer call the tech back., or buy a new one and ask to get reimbursed for the cost.

Is that imbalanced reading happening with the dryer itself on or off?

The cord is brand new.

The dryer wont power on at all so the imbalance is with it off. Should I maybe try replacing my outlet to test a bad connection, even though plug legs read correctly when not on dryer terminal?

Three prongs were ban in 96 for new installs.  Older installs were allowed to be kept, but it is highly recommended to change to to four prongs.  With something wrong, this should be done now.  They were ban because people were dying.

We are assuming the dryer is 240 volts/hot, hot, neutral, and not a 120 volt setup(apartment size washer/dryer).

It is a 240 volt dryer. Is a 4 prong upgrade something I can DIY with proper tools?

This is an electric dryer, right—not gas?

Yes it's electric

If no ground, newer code allows a separate ground wire to be added.  Metal conduit or /3 wire cable with ground not connected is the easiest, ground is there, but just not connected.  This will only improve safety, not the problem you have.

If it is 3-prong, be EXTREMELY wary of it.  A common failure (loss of neutral wire) WILL cause the dryer's chassis to be energized.  See this video about a very similar failure in UK wiring. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE

The black hot had a burn spot in it. Had to run a new one, I guess the first electrician I called missed something or isn't very good
